# nesting Html.DisplayFor within Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a situation where I want to display an Html.ActionLink whose text is the result an Html.DisplayFor call. The reason is that I'm taking advantage of a UIHint attribute on the property I'm displaying--it's a dollar amount with some color-coding based on the amount. The problem is that encoded HTML (a span tag and some styling) is being displayed instead of the rendered output. Here's the razor:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Balance).ToHtmlString(), "Transactions", new { id = item.ID })
```

So, my DisplayFor call is finding the UIHint view code correctly, but like I said, it's returning the raw/encoded HTML instead of the rendered output. Hope that makes sense. The question is how can I get the true rendered output of the DisplayFor call into the ActionLink.

The link target itself is correct, but the link text is broken.

Comment: have you tried Html.Raw in stead of Html.DisplayFor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to try this :

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Transactions", new { id=item.ID})">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Balance)</a>
```

Comment: wow! Will credit your answer in 5 minutes....SO won't let me do it sooner, apparently.